# Raw Http: Handle subdomain

Tags: c#, http, subdomain

I'm practising raw HTTP requests with sockets. I understand how the HTTP protocols works (in basic) and I know how to build a request.

Currently my basic HTTP request is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Connection: Close
```

When I want to request **google.com/toll.php** (which ofcourse does not exists):

```
GET /toll.php HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Connection: Close
```

But what if I have an url that contains a subdomain, like:

```
lol.google.com/toll.php
```

Should the request be:

```
GET /lol/toll.php HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Connection: Close
```

or should it be:

```
GET /toll.php HTTP/1.1
Host: lol.google.com
Connection: Close
```

This problem is driving me nuts! I've read the .NET documentation and sockets and some documentation on the HTTP protocol. I also googled on many terms, but still.. I'm unable to find the answer.

I'm using C# (.NET) and I'm aware that there is no need to write an HTTP class or do manual HTTP request since we have the HttpWebRequest class. This is just for learning purposes.

Thanks in advance.
Swen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should categorically be

```
GET /toll.php HTTP/1.1
Host: lol.google.com
```

Http makes no distinction between domains and subdomains. They're all simply hosts with different names.

Comment: Many thanks for answering my question! I will accept your answer in 9 minutes (That's what StackOverflow tells me) Thanks for the quick response.